# Modifying a paragraph using python-docx and xml

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx, textedit

I want to change a paragraph of a document by changing the XML. For example I need to change the indent after a paragraph:

```
import docx
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

doc = docx.Document('example.docx')
paragraphs = doc.paragraphs

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    p = paragraph._p 
    pPr = OxmlElement('w:pPr')
    spacingp = OxmlElement('w:spacing')
    pPr.append(spacingp)
    p.append(pPr)
    afterp = OxmlElement('w:after')
    afterp.set(qn('w:after'), '0') 
    lineRulep = OxmlElement('w:lineRule')
    lineRulep.set(qn('w:lineRule'), 'auto')
    linep = OxmlElement('w:line')
    linep.set(qn('w:line'), '240')
    spacingp.append(afterp)
    spacingp.append(lineRulep)
    spacingp.append(linep)
    pPr.append(spacingp)
    p.append(pPr)
doc.save('restyled.docx')
```

But this code doesn't work. Please tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: Create a paragraph that _does_ work by hand, using Word. Then inspect the XML it produces using `print paragraph._p.xml`. Compare it to the XML produced by your code and take it from there. Note that the sequence of child elements is usually significant in Word.

Comment: Thank you for advice. In general, I did, but I can't figure out how it should be created using Python code. I tried different options, and this is the most "working" but not performing the necessary actions.